# I don't know why this Python Programming code doesn't work

Tags: python

```
import pygame, sys 
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init() 
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32) 

while True:     
    for event in pygame.event.get():        
        if event.type == QUIT:          
            pygame.quit()           
            sys.exit()          
        screen.lock()           
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (140,240,130), Rect((100,100),(130,170)))
        screen.unlock()     
        pygame.display.update()
```

It's supposed to show a retangle in a 640x360 window, and it doesn't do that, and I don't know why it doesn't do that. Please help me.

Comment: It would clarify things if you fix the indentation in your post.

Comment: what does it do? Do you get an error?

Comment: Please format this code correctly! The level of indentation changes the code's behavior dramatically, i.e are the calls to `pygame.draw` and `pygame.display` nested in the `if event.type == QUIT`? If so then pygame/python will quit before you can draw anything.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better fit for your question.

Comment: but it was indented quite arbitrary by ekruten

Answer (score 2):

It works like that:

[image]

You may be expected to behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me well.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygame, sys 
from pygame.locals import * 
pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32) 
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            screen.lock()
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (140,240,130), Rect((100,100),(130,170)))
            screen.unlock()     
pygame.display.update()
```

Though if you are facing any error, please share the error.